# What does "mob-boss quality" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, figurative

I'm watching Gravity Falls and I've heard a word *"mob-boss"*. Grunkle Stan says *"mob-boss quality"* about faux-gold watches:

[image]

Dictionary says that literally *"mob-boss"* means:

> the head of a criminal organization, esp the Mafia

But I've found no information about using this word in an idiomatic way. I have no clue about the figurative meaning of *"mob-boss quality"* in this context. This is a quality worthy of a head of the Mafia? Or the watches just look rich? What does *"mob-boss quality"* mean?

Comment: Mob bosses stereotypically wear gaudy, tacky jewelry.

Comment: quality means like, here. They are like what a mob boss wears.

Comment: @Lambie How does "*quality mean like*"? Your  comment doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: This ring is "mob-boss quality" means: This ring is **of the quality a mob-boss would wear**. What they are actually trying to say: this ring is like a ring a mob-boss would wear and do so by substituting the term mob boss for the kind of adjective that might accompany the word quality: top quality, great quality, best quality.

Comment: @Casey Thank you! I had not thought about possibility of such interpretation.